# shell command to find common IPs on a specific url from error_log

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

Is there a shell command to group all the most common IPs that requested a specific file via GET (or that came from a url)?

For example with this command I can group requests from ip:

```
cat /usr/local/apache/logs/access_log | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -n 20
```

With this one I can search for "MYURL"

```
grep 'MYURL' /usr/local/apache/logs/access_log | sort -nr | uniq -c | sort -nr -k1 | tail -n 20
```

What I need is to put these 2 commands together and print the most common IPs that requested "MYURL", is that possible?

PS: also it would be nice if the log used is "/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log" and not "access_log"

Comment: yes sorry shell command

Answer (score 3):

You've got all the components you need there - I'm surprised you can't make the jump to combine them yourself. Just change the first command in your first pipeline to the grep at the start of the second one ...

```
grep 'MYURL' /usr/local/apache/logs/access_log | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -n 20
```

I don't understand why you would want to parse `error_log` rather than `access_log` for this - lines in the error log aren't structured like in the access log.

Comment: thank you but it doesn't show the most used IPs in this way

Comment: What does it show? It should give the same report as your first pipeline but only considering log entries for the specified URL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,just convine both with a pipe, and remove what you do not need,

Something like this will do:

```
grep $MYURL /usr/local/apache/logs/access_log | awk '{print $1}' | sort -nu
```